# Remove multiple words from string using list of indexes

Tags: python

`sentence = 'Two Dogs and Three Cats'`

`list_of_indices = [[0,3], [13, 18]]`

I wish to remove multiple indices from a string based on its index position by referencing a nested list of index values (which may have more than 2 elements).

I am able to remove a single index range from the string (e.g remove the word `Two` from the sentence using `S = sentence[:0] + sentence[3:]` but how do I modify this code to remove multiple range of indices by referencing `list_of_indices`?

I tried one other method:

```
to_remove = []

for i in list_of_indices:
    word = sentence[i[0]: i[1]]
    to_remove.append(word)

resultwords  = [word for word in sentence.split() if word not in to_remove]
print(resultwords)
result = ' '.join(resultwords)
print(result)
```

However, it would not work if the word contains other symbols in the sentence e.g. for `sentence = ':Two: Dogs and Three Cats'`, it would not remove `Two`

Comment: You keep using "words" and "letters" interchangeably. Which are you trying to remove? Letters, whole words, or both?

Comment: @blorgon I am trying to remove based on index position, the values are stored in `list_of_indices`

Comment: question: will `list_of_indices` be a sorted list with no overlapping indices?

Comment: @theusaf It is sorted with no overlap

Comment: @abc that doesn't answer my question. "Remove by index position" implies removing single characters, but your code seems to be trying to remove whole words via slicing. Why are you doing it this way? Where are your lists of slice indices coming from? What does your statement at the end claiming "it would not work" mean? If your slice indices are correct then it *would* still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key, I think, is not to think about removing, but to think about what you're keeping.

```
sentence = 'Two Dogs and Three Cats'
list_of_indices = [[0,3], [13, 18]]

keep = []
last = 0
for a,b in list_of_indices:
    keep.append( sentence[last:a] )
    last = b
keep.append(sentence[last:])
print( ''.join(keep) )
```

Output:

```
 Dogs and Cats
```

Answer (score 1):

If complexity isn't a concern, here is an O(NM) approach with the method you suggested, where N is the length of sentence, M is the length of `list_of_indices`. But be aware of the extraneous space introduced between words that you might want to take care of.

```
sentence = 'Two Dogs and Three Cats'

list_of_indices = [[0,3], [13, 18]]


for indices in reversed(list_of_indices):
    sentence = sentence[:indices[0]] + sentence[indices[1]:]

print(sentence)
```

output:

```
Dogs and  Cats
```

Answer (score -1):

You could convert it to a list then add the letters based on index to a new string:

```
word = 'Hello'
indices = [0, 4]

word_list = list(word)
new_word = ''
for index, value in enumerate(word_list):
    if not index in indices:
        new_word += value

print(new_word)
```

Output:

```
ell
```